# Receiving noise signal on input pin after connecting jumper wire to GPIO pin Raspberry pi 4

Tags: pi-4, rpi.gpio, signal

I am trying to use GPIO pin to get input from the sensonr, after connecting the sensor I noticed I have a lot of noise ( fluctuating signals between 0 and one). After further troubleshooting I noticed some abnoral phonamena.
My Raspberry Pi input pin shows constant "1" input when nothing is connected to the pin, however as soon as I connec a jumper wire to the pin ( currently using GPIO pin 27, but I test this with other pins like GPIO 20 and GPIO21 with the same result) input signal keeps fluctuating between 0 and 1.)
I also moved the Raspberry pi to different location in case I was getting this signal from nearby cable and it didnt help.

Here is the code that I am using with different output,if I remove the jumper wire I get the first plot ( which means there is no noise), and as soon as I connect the jumper wire I get the second plot.
Anyone has any idea why this is happening? Is my raspberry pi damaged? I have done this before and didnt have this issue.

```
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

RECEIVED_SIGNAL = [[], []]  #[[time of reading], [signal reading]]
MAX_DURATION = 15
RECEIVE_PIN = 27


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(RECEIVE_PIN, GPIO.IN)
    cumulative_time = 0
    beginning_time = datetime.now()
    print ('**Started recording**')
    while cumulative_time < MAX_DURATION:
        time_delta = datetime.now() - beginning_time
        RECEIVED_SIGNAL[0].append(time_delta)
        print(GPIO.input(RECEIVE_PIN))
        RECEIVED_SIGNAL[1].append(GPIO.input(RECEIVE_PIN))
        cumulative_time = time_delta.seconds
    print ('**Ended recording**')
    print (len(RECEIVED_SIGNAL[0]), 'samples recorded')
    GPIO.cleanup()

    print ('**Processing results**')
    for i in range(len(RECEIVED_SIGNAL[0])):
        RECEIVED_SIGNAL[0][i] = RECEIVED_SIGNAL[0][i].seconds + RECEIVED_SIGNAL[0][i].microseconds/1000000.0

    print ('**Plotting results**')
    pyplot.plot(RECEIVED_SIGNAL[0], RECEIVED_SIGNAL[1])
    pyplot.axis([0, MAX_DURATION, -1, 2])
    pyplot.show()
```

[image: Constant signla wihtout jumper wire]
[image: Noisy signal after connecting jumper wire]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until a voltage is applied to a GPIO it will float between high and low.

https://www.mouser.com/blog/dont-leave-your-pins-floating

Comment: Yes, and to emphasize what "float" means to a new user, it **does not** mean that the voltage will be zero and it **does not** mean that the voltage will always alternate between a logic 1 and logic 0.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer, I read about floating while ago and totally forgot about it. Now I am going to see what is the best way to remove noise for RF433 receiver as I dont think I can use pull up/down resistor on that. But at least I dont have the floating issue when nothing is connected to the pin.

Comment: You will get noise on a RF433 receiver until there is a signal present.  Not much you can do about that.  I use a glitch filter with pigpio.  See http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python__433_py